# Problems with trackbar and Django

Tags: javascript, django

I have a little problem. I use Django like a web-framework and when i try to include trackbar to the html-file this trackbar just not displayed. When I include trackbar to the simple html-file everything is ok. But when I run my application with Django, trackbar just not displayed. I don't know where is problem.

```
 <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="trackbar.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript" src="trackbar.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript"> 
trackbar.getObject('two').init({
onMove : function() {       
},
dual : false,
width : 300, 
leftLimit : 0, 
leftValue : 0, 
rightLimit : 180, 
rightValue : 180    
});</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Too much ambiguity to bother. Try to clarify what exactly works and what not!

Comment: Well, all blog <script>...</script> don't work

Comment: have you included {% load staticfiles %}?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because 'two' isn't an object or a selector on that page.

See here:

```
trackbar.getObject('two').init({
```

If you're trying to reference a selector using a class or id, they need `.two` or `#two`, respectively.

If that's supposed to be an actual object, take it out of the quotes.

The way it is now, it's just a string that says 'two'.